# Why is my hamburger menu not shown?

Tags: menus, css, genesis-theme-framework

I use Genesis Digital Pro theme and my responsive menu is not shown on mobile devices. 
There is block in page that contains my menu, and it opens when you click this area, but I want the hamburger to be shown from the start (as it supposed to work). What to do?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If it's a Pro theme, you should ask them for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hamburger is shown with ionicons as an `after` element. You have conflicting CSS in your theme.

This (specifically, the `content: " ";`) CSS:

```
.entry:before, .entry-content:before, .nav-primary:before, .site-container:before, .site-header:before, .site-inner:before, .wrap:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
```

is overwriting the hamburger menu's CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .menu-toggle:before, .menu-toggle.activated:before {
    color: #1e1e1e;
    content: "\f130";
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal 20px/1 'ionicons';
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

Here's a devtools screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjoXV.png

Comment: Thank you very much! Now my hamburger is shown in all its deliciousness!